# pros and cons of two definitions of container_of(ptr, type, member)

Tags: c, macros

in some codebase I see a definition of the `container_of()` macro like this:

```
#ifndef container_of
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) \
    ({ \
        const typeof(((type *)0)->member) *__mptr = (ptr); \
        (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type, member) ); \
    })     /* definition 1 */
#else
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) \
    ((type *)((char *)(ptr) - offsetof(type, member)))  /* definition 2 */
#endif
#endif // container_of
```

To me, *definition 2* seems reasonable enough, whereas in *definition 1* the author use GCC's `typeof` keyword to obtain the type of `ptr`, and then cast it to `char *`, rendering the `typeof` statement useless.

What is the rationale behind *definition 1*? And if *definition 1* is actually useful, what are two definitions's pros and cons?